# Visual Studio 2017 missing tools on MAC OS X

Tags: macos, visual-studio-mac

I am using VS 2017 Community Edition but I have some missing tools such as in controller when I right click on actionresult I cannot find go to / add view option as you seen in the image

[image: VS 2017 Missing tool]

VS is up to date there is no more update.How can I get full tools of VS for mac ? I have deleted and re-installed but still same Also I need to change my vs type to enterprise. I logged in with my account which has license  on windows with enterprise vs but in mac it is community even if I download enterprise.

Comment: Visual Studio for Mac is not Visual Studio for Windows. The missing features are far too many to count. Treat it as a new product, and wait for Microsoft to add such.

Comment: but other people say they have and microsoft says they fixed it in new update but I didnt have it. and right click add view is the basic must have of visual studio but I think u are right

Comment: Then come after that "other people". "Microsoft says"? Then make sure you have a real information source.

Comment: There is currently no support for right clicking on an ActionResult and going to the view in Visual Studio for Mac when using an ASP.NET Core project. ASP.NET Core projects currently have no MVC support when compared with the older ASP.NET project, which does have the feature you mention. Visual Studio for Mac has a User Voice page where you can vote or add features you would like to see supported and helps the team prioritise work - https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/563332-visual-studio-for-mac